# android mailto code not functioning properly

Tags: android, mailto

```
package com.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.MailTo;
import android.content.Context;


public class HelloWorld extends Activity
{
    final Activity activity = this;


    WebView webview;
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (webview != null && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.blahblah.org");

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if(progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        });

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String       description, String failingUrl)
            {
            // Handle the error
            }

     @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            if(url.startsWith("mailto:")){
                MailTo mt = MailTo.parse(url);
                Intent i = newEmailIntent(activity.this, mt.getTo(), mt.getSubject(), mt.getBody(), mt.getCc());
                startActivity(i);
                view.reload();
                return true;
            }

             view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    });
}
    public static Intent newEmailIntent(Context context, String address, String subject, String body, String cc) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { address });
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        return intent;
    }
}
```

The code above runs properly except when a mailto link is clicked, the device messenger opens up and doesn't place the mailto "body" in the compose section of the messenger.  The same mailto link works properly in devices web browser.  Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my testing,
but it turned out that using the `text/plain` type,
it was trying to send an SMS.

I think you want to change two things.

```
intent.setType("text/html");
```

But also you should use the `Intent.createChooser`.

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Some prompt for the user:"));
```

Especially with email, they may have both the android email app and the gmail app installed.
Or they may have no app installed that is capable of sending html emails.

This fixed a problem for me on the emulator, where it kept breaking.

Here's the full code for my working email sender.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, EMAIL_TO);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, EMAIL_SUBJECT);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, EMAIL_TEXT);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email to the Author:"));
```

Update:

reading the question again
you should probably add some debugging, make sure its not the mailto parsing that is wrong.

```
String tag = "emaildebug";
Log.d(tag, "address: "+address);
Log.d(tag, "body:    "+body);
Log.d(tag, "subject: "+subject);
Log.d(tag, "cc:      "+cc);
```

Comment: I wasnt sure exactly how to implement your code in the code above.  One thing I did do is change the order in the newEmailIntent line with mt.getBody first.  When I run the app the body of the mailto link gets placed in the composition section of the messenger but the link is cut off.  It looks like the mailto code is not recognizing "http" addresses and "?" in the links.

Comment: I think that your question is phrased wrongly. You're problem, I'd guess is in fact to do with the fact that your mailto looks like `mailto:me@example.com?body=some+link+to+http://example.com?query=something`. This certainly won't work. You need to escape the url. Something like `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%3Fquery%3Dsomething`

Comment: I changed the :, ? and / with the correct url encoding.  The body and subject still is not getting prefilled in the messenger when clicking the link in webview.  The exact same link works perfect in other browsers.

Comment: In what language is the <a href="mailto.... written in.Couse if it is in javascript , i can provide with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Still no bug fix for this problem:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22684